# To find the orientation of given 2 non collinear vectors in space

Tags: vector-spaces

If a and b are non collinear vectors,then how will the orientation of 
(a/mod(a))+(b/mod(b)) with respect to a and b vectors?
Or will the vector be unit vector or something?
Please  explain.
The answer could be any of these;
a unit vector or in the plane of a and b or perpendicular to a and b or parallel to a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not a unit vector, but it lies surely in the plane of a and b.
Every vector of the form $\alpha a+\beta b$ lies there. It's actually the definition of the plane.

Comment: but a and b here are vectors.

Comment: Yes, they are. What is the problem?

Comment: So in this equation αa+βb alpha,beta are constants and 1/mod(a) and 1/mod(b) are constants so you say it lies surely in the plane of a and b.

Comment: Yes, it is so..

Comment: But what would be the case if you consider the cases  perpendicular to a and b or parallel to a and b.Please explain both these cases,and why are they ruled out.

Comment: The vector $a/\|a\|+b/\|b\|$ can be  parallel to $a$ only if $a$ and $b$ are collinear. The same for $b$. The proof is easy: $a/\|a\|+b/\|b\|$ is parallel to $a$ => $\exists \alpha$ such that $a/\|a\|+b/\|b\|=\alpha a$ => $a(\alpha-1/\|a\|)=b/\|b\|$ => $a,b$ are collinear.

Comment: The vector $a/\|a\|+b/\|b\|$ can be perpendicular to $a$ or to $b$ in some cases.But not in all cases. You are not asked to analyse these cases, so I wouldn't do it.